# Git for Windows client only showing my commits now

Tags: git, github, git-commit

I work with a team of programmers on a group project hosted on GitHub.  Up until yesterday everything was fine.  Some of us use the Git Desktop for Windows client while others use the GitHub Shell.  I usually use the shell, but today a team member reported that only my commits show up in his history list for commits; no other team member's commits are visible.

However:

- An older version of Git Desktop for Windows does show all the commits from every team member properly
- The browser/web interface for GitHub shows everything properly.
- All repos and branches appear to be there and intact

It's just this newer version of GitHub that is showing only my commits.  Has anybody else seen this issue and knows how to fix it?

The new version of Git Desktop for Windows that seems to have this problem (at least for us) is : The Last Free Monad 3.0.3.1

Comment: About 9 months later..  This is  the same issues i am facing. I use the git Desktop for Mac. I can see commits from only one person in my team. Yesterday it was a different person. Did you find out any reason or resource ?